# changes to domain group membership not showing for user in SLES 11 SP3

Tags: suse, sles, active-directory

Joined server `linux02` runing SUSE enterprise linux server service pack 3 to a Windows active directory domain `example.com` no problem.

Users, like `fred` from the domain can login no problem via `ssh EXAMPLE\\fred@linux02.example.com`

When logged in as domain user, running `groups` command shows all domain groups no problem.

Logout `fred` and reboot `linux02`

On Windows domain controller, make `fred` a member of group `linux_sudoers`

`fred` logs into `linux02` and runs `groups` command, but **only all the old groups** are displayed. Problem: `fred` doesn't appear to be a member of `linux_sudoers`

Now when running `wbinfo --group-info=EXAMPLE\\linux_sudoers`, low and behold he appears to be a member:
`EXAMPLE\linux_sudoers:x:10073:EXAMPLE\fred`
But when running `groups` again, the new group still isn't in the list.

Now back on the Windows domain controller, I create a new user `john` and make him a member of `linux_sudoers`

`john` is now able to login to `linux02` no problem, and when running the `groups` command shows he is a member of `linux_sudoers`

Subsequent tests show that a user is essentially locked into the domain group memberships that existed at the time of first login to `linux02` and no changes from the domain will ever reflect regardless of logging out or even rebooting the server. I'm out of ideas. Any hints out there?

### Answer:

**@David King** was right! Specifically, I needed to run these commands:

```
service smbfs stop
service winbind stop
rm -rf /var/lib/samba/*tdb
```

I didn't have any files in /var/cache/samba/

```
service smbfs start
service winbind start
```

Logged in with `fred` and ran `groups` and sure enough he shows as a member of `linux_sudoers`

Thanks **@David King**!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is a timeout.  Linux is caching the group memberships and not renewing them until the timeout expires.  It's super annoying.  The even more annoying part is that the only way I've found to force it to update is to delete the caches

```
/etc/init.d/samba stop
rm -rf /var/cache/samba/* /var/lib/samba/*tdb
/etc/init.d samba start
```

I don't use SLES so you might need to do adjust this to fit how SLES starts/stops services but the important thing to note is that samba and winbind *must* be stopped when you delete the caches.